# Checking for multiple variable value in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, user-interface, alerts

I am creating an iPhone app which is taking many values from the user and assigning them to variables.

I want to display an alert message if more than two of the variables' values are equal to zero.

Basically, if the user has two empty fields, it should show an alert stating that there is insufficient data.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I guess you'd count the number of zeros.

Comment: Are you certain this question conveys what you're trying to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague but what about

1. Find errors
2. Display an alert

Somewhere alone the lines of this pseudo code:

```
int errorCount = 0;

if(var1 == 0) {
    errorCount++;
}

if(var2 == 0) {
    errorCount++;
}

// check all variables...

// Show alert if there are any errors
if(errorCount > 0) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
              initWithTitle:@"Title"
              message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have %d errors", errorCount]
              delegate:nil
              cancelButtonTitle:@"GoFightWin"
              otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];   
}
```